# todatestring without the name of the day at the beginning

Tags: javascript

I want toDateString without the name of the day at the beginning.

```js
var d = new Date();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.toDateString();
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `String#slice()` (or other substring methods) since the day lengths are uniform

```js
var d = new Date();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.toDateString().slice(4);
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 3):

[MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/) was made for this. Any possible date format you can imagine.

```js
var d = new Date();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = moment(d).format("MMM DD YYYY")
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = moment(d).format("LLL")
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = moment(d).format("lll")
document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = moment(d).format("L")
document.getElementById("demo4").innerHTML = moment(d).format("LL")
document.getElementById("demo5").innerHTML = moment(d).format("ll")
document.getElementById("demo6").innerHTML = moment(d).format("llll")
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<p id="demo" />
<p id="demo1" />
<p id="demo2" />
<p id="demo3" />
<p id="demo4" />
<p id="demo5" />
<p id="demo6" />
```

Answer (score 2):

using [`toLocaleDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

```js
var d = new Date();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.toLocaleDateString('en-US', {
  day: 'numeric',
  month: 'short',
  year: 'numeric'
});
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can **`split`** on space and take elements except **`first element`** and than **`join`** them again with space

```html
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var d = new Date();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.toDateString().split(' ').slice(1,).join(' ');
</script>
```