# Update Target Google Sheet via Script using api v4

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

For this problem, consider 2 Google Sheets:

***1. Sheet 1:***

- Name: Source
- Function: Central Data Repository for plans and forecast

***2. Sheet 2:***

- Name: Working Document
- Function: Working Document that loads data from the central source document (using ImportRange). The data from the central document is the reviewed in light of other new business data and the forecast is adjusted, reviewed and finalised

*****Requirement:*****

- After the new forecast is reviewed and approved, the "Source" sheet needs to be updated
- The update needs to happen via a script
- The script will essentially push the data from the "Working Document" to the "Source Document"
- The data in the source document needs to be updated and not simply appended

***What I have managed to achieve already:***

- Instead of simply updating the data that's already there, I have adopted a 2 step proces:
- *Step 1:* Delete the updated records from the "Source" sheet (used the *batchUpdate* method to build an array of matching rows to delete using the "deleteDimension" property)
- *Step 2:* Append the updated records from the "Working Document" into the "Source Document" (used the *Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.append* method)

***Questions:***

1. Is it possible to perform the update in one step? ie. locate the changed row in the "Source" and then just update that row?
2. After going through reference manuals, I have come across the [batchUpdateByDataFilter](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdateByDataFilter) method - I am hoping / assuming that this does what I mentioned above in Question 1 (ie. filter the data and then batch update?), but I cant really make sense of the documentation which does not provide clear and comprehensive code samples for this. Can someone please confirm if this is possible and if this is what *batchUpdateByDataFilter* does.
3. If it is not what it does (see above question), can you please explain what it does do, and what the difference between *batchUpdateByDataFilter* and *batchUpdate* is; right now I am a bit confused around how to do this most efficiently.

***Additional information:***

Sample Data: Source Data

| Date | Product | Country | Forecast |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `1-Jan-23` | `ABC001` | `USA` | `100` |
| `8-Jan-23` | `ABC001` | `USA` | `200` |
| `15-Jan-23` | `ABC001` | `USA` | `500` |
| 1-Jan-23 | XYZ002 | UK | 10 |
| 8-Jan-23 | XYZ002 | UK | 20 |
| 15-Jan-23 | XYZ002 | UK | 50 |

*Practical Example:*
If we need to just update the forecast for Product "*ABC001*" and just for the Country = "*USA*" (rows highlighted) - using the API what would be the most efficient way to do this using the sheets api?

Thanks in advance - sorry for the long post, just wanted to provide as much context as possible

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? By the way, what is your bottom table? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: The input and output are the same (structure), I am trying to update the source document from the working document using the sheets API

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from `The input and output are the same (structure), I am trying to update the source document from the working document using the sheets API`, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Ok, do you see the sample table provided under "additional information" that table is in both the "source" google sheet and the 'working document" sheet. I would like to update the "source" document, with the changes made in the "working document"

Comment: @Tanaike - how do you copy changes made from sheet 1 to sheet 2 using batchupdate method on Google sheets api via script?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use the API vs just a Google Apps Script? I'm sure you could get this working via API HTTP requests, but it would be simpler to do via an embedded script. Depending on your needs, you could set up a nightly trigger to update your source sheet from the working doc, or you could have users push updates when they are ready.

Comment: @MiguelRiveraRios - yes, I am referring to a script, but the library is called sheets api v4, so it would be coded in google apps script

Comment: @Tanaike - did my explanation make it a bit more clear? What do you think, how can we make this work?

Comment: I am trying to understand your process: `Working Document` ("WD") pulls data from `Source` via `IMPORTRANGE`. 1) How do you establish the range value for `IMPORTRANGE`? 2) Is the adjusted forecast for WD entered in an adjacent column on the same row as the referenced forecast? 3) `After the new forecast is reviewed and approved...` Please explain how the "approved" status of an adjusted, reviewed forecast is identified on WD. i.e. how does one know which forecast to update to Source. 4) When a forecast is altered, is the forecast "date" also altered?

Comment: `Update Target Google Sheet via Script using api v4`, `Looking for something similar in function to SQL UPDATE or SQL REPLACE` and `but the library is called sheets api v4`. I'm sorry I am confused. I do not understand why you want to use the API to update the the value in `Source`. A fairly simple `onEdit` script will (I have tested one with your scenario and can provide as an answer if you wish) update the adjusted forecast to Source without any complication. A key issue is, I think, how do you expect to trigger any update from `Working Document` to `Source`?

Comment: @Tedinoz - Regarding workflow: 1. I select the product from a drop down 2. The forecast populates in the WD from an importrange function. 3. A macro copies and pastes the forecast as values (overwriting the importrange formula). 4. I make changes to the forecast (pasted values) as needed. 5. I press an update button to apply changes of the forecats back to the source -> point 5 is where I need help. How do you update the source with information from WD

Comment: @Tedinoz - just answering some of your other questions: "`Please explain how the "approved" status of an adjusted, reviewed forecast is identified on WD`" - on the WD, I compare the new / approved forecast to the original information pulled from the Source using importrange, if there are differences an update is required to the Source to apply changes

Comment: @Tedinoz - replying to: "`I'm sorry I am confused. I do not understand why you want to use the API to update the the value in Source`"

I'm not wanting to use an actual API, on the google documentation they refer to the latest methods as "sheets api v4". see this link: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate

Like you said, using `onEdit` we can interact with sheets (CRUD operations) using these methods eg.`Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests: requests }, spreadsheetId);` where `requests` is a formed array payload inline with API spec

Answer (score 1):

You have two spreadsheets: "Source", which contains a central Repository of data, and "Working Document" (WD), which is used for developing updates of Forecast data.

The OP

Your question is: `How to update "Source" with information from "WD" using API v4 methods?? Looking for something similar in function to SQL UPDATE or SQL REPLACE`

The OP does not flag rows on WD that have changed - all rows are assumed to have changed. While there are many simple alternatives, work-arounds and trigger options to flag the rows to be updated (and thereby improve speed and efficiency) this will be left to the OP.

Regarding `API v4 methods`, I believe that the OP has a mistaken understanding that the documentation somehow suggests/recommends the use of the API. This understanding is not correct. Possibly the OP expects that the API will `automatically and dynamically update` "Source" data from "WD"; I don't believe that this is the case and I don't see any advantage attached to using the V4 API.

This answer works as follows:

- the concatenated value of the date, product, country and forecast is a unique value.
- an array is unique values is built for "Source" data
- there is a loop of "WD" data (for which the `forecast` may or may not have been changed)

  - using `indexOf`, the value of each WD unique value is compared against the array of unique "Source" values
  - when/if the WD value is NOT found,

    - the loop variable identifies the relevant sheet row.
    - the "Source" array data forecast value is updated for the revised "WD" forecast value
- after the loop, the "Source" data range is updated for the adjusted array values.

---

```
function updateChanges() {
  var workingSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2")
  var sourceId = "<<INSERT SPREADSHEET ID>>"
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceId)
  var sourceSheet = source.getSheetByName("Sheet1")

  // get the 'Source' datasourceForecasts
  var HeaderRow = 1
  var lastRow = sourceSheet.getLastRow()
  var sourceDataRange = sourceSheet.getRange(HeaderRow+1,1,lastRow-1,4)
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: 'Source' data range = "+sourceDataRange.getA1Notation())
  var sourceData = sourceDataRange.getValues()
 
  // create an array of concatenated data values
  var sourceDataArray = new Array
    for (var i=0;i<sourceData.length;i++){
    sourceDataArray.push(getFormattedDate(sourceData[i][0])+sourceData[i][1]+sourceData[i][2]+sourceData[i][3])
  }
  // Logger.log(sourceDataArray) // DEBUG

  // create a 1D array for indexOf
  var source1DForecasts = sourceData.map(function(e){return e[3];});//[[e],[e],[e]]=>[e,e,e]
  // Logger.log(source1DForecasts) // DEBUG

  // get Working Document Data
  var workingDataRange = workingSheet.getRange(HeaderRow+1,1,lastRow-1,4)
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: 'Working' data range: "+workingDataRange.getA1Notation())
  var workingData = workingDataRange.getValues()
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: number of records on workingData: "+workingData.length)

  // loop through 'WD' data to find match on 'Source'
  for (var i=0;i<workingData.length;i++){
    var uniqueWDValue = getFormattedDate(workingData[i][0])+workingData[i][1]+workingData[i][2]+workingData[i][3]
    var result = sourceDataArray.indexOf(uniqueWDValue)
    if (result == -1){
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: Matched: i: "+i+", unique value: "+uniqueWDValue+", indexOf result: "+result)
      var sourceTargetCell = sourceSheet.getRange(i+HeaderRow+1,4) // add 1 for zero-based result
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: target cell: "+sourceTargetCell.getA1Notation()+", original forecast: "+sourceData[i][3]+", revised forecast: "+workingData[i][3]) 
      sourceData[i][3] = workingData[i][3]
    }
    else{
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: NOT Matched: i: "+i+", unique value = "+uniqueWDValue+", indexOf result = "+result)
    }
  } // end of loop


  // update the 'Source' sheet
  sourceDataRange.setValues(sourceData)

}

// ht: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55431280/1330560
// user: User863
function getFormattedDate(date) {
    let year = date.getFullYear();
    //Logger.log("year: "+year)
    let month = (1 + date.getMonth()).toString().padStart(2, '0');
    //Logger.log("month: "+month)
    let day = date.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
    //Logger.log("day; "+day)
  
    return day + '-' + month + '-' + year;
}
```

---

**Sample Data: SOURCE**

[image: snapshot]

Comment: Thanks for that response - not exactly what I was looking for, but you did get me thinking about creating a primary key on the source, and pull that through to WD so that when I update back to the source I can build out the `requests`  payload from the api v4 (Batchupdate method) and explicitly define the rows from the PK

Comment: Also, just to address some of the things mentioned above:
`the OP has a mistaken understanding that the documentation somehow suggests/recommends the use of the API` and  `I don't see any advantage attached to using the V4 API.`

This is not right, I understand that  google sheets api v4 is a more efficient way of interacting with google sheets via script and is the latest, best and most efficient coding Framework for CRUD operations on sheets via code - please see this video as an example:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VLdrgE8iJZI&t=149s&ab_channel=GoogleforDevelopers

Comment: `the OP expects that the API will automatically and dynamically update "Source" data from "WD` - I did not mention automatic updates - the workflow described said, 1. load forecast, 2. review and make changes, 3. Once changes are approved, save and update the source document. By using the word "dynamic" do you suggest that only updated rows are modified in source? I dont understand this comment...

Comment: `By using the word "dynamic" do you suggest that only updated rows are modified in source?` Yes.

Comment: `please see this video as an example:` I think that you are missing the point. Though there are times when one might find methods in the API that don't existing in apps-script, by and large the API is a tool that enables you to `connect apps to Google Sheets`. As Google said when they introduced the API [Our new APIs let developers connect their apps—and the data within them—more deeply with Google Sheets](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/apps-dev-sheets-api?utm_campaign=drive_launch_google_sheets_api_061416&utm_source=gdev&utm_medium=yt-desc).